# An entire Dirichlet series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Let $\{a(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real number, suh that for any $C\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$a(n)\ll_{C}n^{C}$$  My question : is how we can prove that the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)^2}{n^s}$$ converges for all $s\in \mathbb{C}.$

Many thanks

Comment: By $a(n)\ll_{C}n^{C}$ do you mean that for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$, we have a $b_C$ so that $\left|a(n)\right|\le b_Cn^C$?

Comment: @robjohn, yes  $\;\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an $s\in\mathbb{C}$, we have a $b$ so that $\left|a(n)\right|\le bn^{\mathrm{Re}(s/2)-1}$ (let $C=\mathrm{Re}(s/2)-1$). Then
$$
\left|\frac{a(n)^2}{n^s}\right|\le\frac{b^2}{n^2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(n)^2}{n^s}
$$
converges absolutely by comparison.

Comment: Mister Johnson, I have a similar question :  the sequence $\{a(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ satisfy $a(n)\ll_{\epsilon}n^{k-1+2\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and I wanna prove that the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)^2}{n^s}$ converges for $\Re(s)>2k-1$ but I don't know how I can choose $\epsilon.$ Could you Could you give me a hint ? Many thanks

Comment: Can you see that you need $\overbrace{2k-2+4\epsilon}^{\text{exponent of $n$ in the numerator}}-\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \mathrm{Re}(s)\ \ \ \ }^{\text{exponent of $n$ in the denominator}}\lt-1$?

Comment: Yes this imply convergence for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>2k-1+4\epsilon$ so we must choose $\epsilon=0$ but the inequality  $a(n)^2\ll_{\epsilon}n^{2k-2+4\epsilon}$ satisfied just for $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: Why must you choose $\epsilon=0$? All you need is that $4\epsilon\lt \mathrm{Re}(s)-(2k-1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.